# Playing Sound from server using Media Player

Tags: android, audio, stream, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play a sound in android using media player with no success,

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108022472/5041046.mp3"; 
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
              public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                  mp.start();
              }
            });
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();


    }
```

I'm getting this from logcat:

```
prepareAsync called in state 1
```

Anything wrong in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already prepared by calling prepare().  There's no need to call prepareAsync() if you already called prepare().  Drop one of those two calls.

Comment: thanks, in fact you are right, its just that I forgot to add internet permission to the manifest file